# US Preclearance time at Abu Dhabi - (AUH - MAN - ORD)

Tags: usa, transit, pre-clearance, auh

This is my first time going to US. I going to book a ticket in Etihad airlines traveling from Chennai to Chicago with layovers at Abu Dhabi (2 hours 20 minutes transit time) and Manchester. My question is,

1) Will I be allowed to enter US preclearance at Abu Dhabi since I must change flight at Manchester? If so, is 2 hours enough to clear the preclearance and board the flight?

2) If I make it to Manchester after US preclearance, should I check-in my luggage there, or the airline would take care of it?

Answer (score 5):

Preclearance can only be used when you are flying nonstop from the preclearance airport to the US.  So you won't go through preclearance in Abu Dhabi.  And Manchester doesn't have preclearance, so you will clear US immigration and customs when you arrive in Chicago.